# Using Python's distutils.core, compiler links in Python 2.7 instead of Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, swig, distutils

I've got a package with swig wrapping C for Python that I'm trying to upgrade to Python 3.  I'm building it under Linux (CentOS) (provided in a Docker environment).

My problem is that the compile and link options assume I'm using Python 2.7.  That is, the compile includes

-I/usr/include/python2.7

and the link includes

-lpython2.7

I got the compilation to work by including a compile option to find the Python 3 include directory:

```
CC="gcc -I/usr/include/python3.6m" python setup.py build_ext
```

but the link is failing due to not finding the python2.7 library:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How do I tell distutils I'm a Python 3 shop now?  "python" already gives "python3".

Comment: [`swig -python -py3`](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Python.html#Python_commandline) ?

Comment: This is the command line to tell swig that you use python3. I will recommend that you simply use the distutils from Python3, e.g. in virtual environment. Check also the `setup.py` script if there is anything pointing to python 2.7

Comment: Thanks, phd.  I'll try to figure out how to get -py3 to the swig command (I don't give it explicitly; distutils figures it out from a source being ".i").

Comment: Thank you, Jens.  I thought I was running setup.py with Python 3, because I have an alias of "python" -> "python3", but that wasn't respected by the calling (Python 3) script.  Explicitly asking for python3 in the calling script fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

As Jens pointed out, though I thought I was calling setup.py with Python 3, I was actually using Python 2.  Fixing that to Python 3 solved my problem.